# A gibberish question closed as "unclear"

Tags: support, vote-to-close, close-reasons, closed-questions, unclear

[qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51555760/)

That question (title is a bunch of "q"s and body is a bunch of "."s) was closed as "unclear what you're asking." Is it a proper use of the close reason? I thought nonsense/gibberish questions would get deleted.

Comment: It's easier to delete the question once it's already closed.

Comment: That question was vandalized after it was closed. Rolling back the edit would be the desired action.. except I'd prefer to delete it instead in this case.

Comment: Even without the vandalism.... What other reason would fit? We don't have a reason for 'pure gibberish'....but I think it is fair to say the question is unclear, no? You can clearly get what the OP was getting at?

Comment: @Patrice Yes we have, it's called "abusive".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It was not exactly gibberish from the [beginning](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/51555760/1):

> how to design custom review form for my product in woocommerce step by step procedure?
>
> how to design custom review for single product . Step By Step Procedure For this. how to add field and database

This got closed as unclear. The question was then self-vandalized by the author. This would normally be rolled back, but why bother if it's on its way to automatic deletion already.